# Is $\mathbb R$ a normal topological space?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, separation-axioms

As in the title, in euclidean space is it always possible two find for two disjoint closed sets $A,B$ two open sets $U,V$ disjoint such that $A \subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq V$ (T4-property, normal)?

Comment: Somebody has to say it, might as well be me: Yes, _perfectly normal_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Every metric space is normal, in particular $\mathbb R^n$. The proof goes as follows:

For each $a\in A$, let $r_a=\frac{1}{3}d(a,B)$, and for each $b\in B$, let $s_b=\frac{1}{3}d(b,A)$. Now define $U=\bigcup_{a\in A}B(a,r_a)$  and $V=\bigcup_{b\in B}B(b,s_b)$. It is not hard to show that $A\subseteq U,$ $B\subseteq V,$ and $U\cap V=\varnothing$.

Comment: thank you, does this imply that it is not possible to find two closed disjoint sets $A,B$ such $d(A;B) = inf\{d(a,b): a\in A,b\in B\} = 0$?

Comment: @stefan No, it doesn't. For example, take $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: y\leq 0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: y\geq e^x\}$

Comment: you are right! but I was thinking on subsets of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Stefan It also fails for $\mathbb R$, take $A=\{n\in\mathbb  Z: n\geq 1\}$ and $B=\{n+\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb Z, n\geq 1\}$.

Comment: I know its super late but could you describe why $U\cap V=\emptyset?$ Like, suppose $p \in U\cap V$ then $p\in \bigcup_{a\in A}B(a,r_a)\implies \exists B(a,r_a):p\in B(a,r_a)$ and $p\in \bigcup_{b\in B}B(b,s_b)\implies \exists B(b,s_b):p\in B(b,s_b)$. But from here how the contradiction part arise? @azarel

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory $d(a,p) \leq r_{a} = \frac{1}{3}d(a,B) \leq \frac{1}{3}d(a,b)$...similarly, $d(p,b) \leq s_{b} = \frac{1}{3}d(b,A) \leq \frac{1}{3}d(b,a)$. Thus, we get $d(a,b) \leq d(a,p) + d(p,b) \leq \frac{1}{3}d(a,b) + \frac{1}{3}d(b,a)$....a contradiction!